# Is it possible to have more than one datePattern for dojo dijit/form/DateTextBox

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

In dojo dijit/form/DateTextBox for example

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <input type="text" name="testDate" data-dojo-id="testDate" class="dateTextBox" value="" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" id="scheduledDate" data-dojo-props="constraints:{datePattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy|MMddyyyy'}">
```

in this you all can see, that I am trying to use two date formats. But this is working for the format that is first, in this case MM/dd/yyyy. But MMddyyyy is not working.

Please help me out in this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the widget itself. The reason for this is that the `datePattern` is used for both input and output. Because you can only show one output, there can only be one pattern. If I run your example and select a data from the dropdown, then the output is 12/08/2012|12082012 for the date 8 december 2012. What it does behind the screens is use the pattern directly to parse/format using the `dojo/date/locale` module which doesn't support regular expressions (it's just a simple date pattern).

However, it is not entirely impossible to achieve, you might extend the `dijit/form/DateTextBox` and make it work so that there are different patterns for input and output. Look at the code of the [`diji/form/_DateTimeTextBox`](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/form/_DateTimeTextBox.js). On line 77 you can see the `parse` method that actually converts the input string to a date. You will have to override this function.

An example of overriding the widget is by doing:

```js
declare("custom/DateTextBox", [DateTextBox], {
    parse: function(value, constraints) {
        var out = null;
        if (constraints.inputDatePattern !== undefined) {
            var patterns = constraints.inputDatePattern.split('|');
            for (var idx = 0; idx < patterns.length && out === null; idx++) {
                out = this.dateLocaleModule.parse(value, lang.mixin(constraints, {
                    datePattern: patterns[idx] 
                }));
            }
        } else {
            out = this.inherited(arguments);     
        }
        return out || (this._isEmpty(out) ? null : undefined);
    }
});
```

What I actually do here is introducing a new constraint called `inputDatePattern`, used to parse the input (while `datePattern` will be used for the output). If the `inputDatePattern` is not defined, I use the original function to parse the input. If it is defined, then I split the pattern by the pipe symbol (`|`) and try each pattern until I get a correct value.

All together this results in a custom datetextbox. You have to change your HTML as well until you et something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RkJa2/1/).

Comment: I am new to dojo and so suggest me some other way or give me some working example. I did not understand the things inside the link that you gave.